# Multi-index pandas dataframes: find an index related to the number of unique values a column has

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

```
# import Pandas library
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A001', 'B001','C001'],
                              ['0', '1', '2']],
                             names=['ID', 'Entries'])
col = ['A', 'B']

df = pd.DataFrame('-', idx, col)
df.loc['A001', 'A'] = [10,10,10]
df.loc['A001', 'B'] = [90,84,70]
df.loc['B001', 'A'] = [10,20,10]
df.loc['B001', 'B'] = [70,86,67]
df.loc['C001', 'A'] = [20,20,20]
df.loc['C001', 'B'] = [98,81,72]
#df is a dataframe
df
```

Following is the problem: How to return the ID which has more than one unique values for column 'A'? In the above dataset, ideally it should return B001.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me out with performing operations in multi-index pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and for values of first levl of `MultiIndex` add [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.unique.html):

```
a = df[df.groupby(level=0)['A'].transform('nunique') > 1].index.get_level_values(0).unique()
print(a)
Index(['B001'], dtype='object', name='ID')
```

Or use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), but first need columns from `MultiIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
m = df.reset_index().duplicated(subset=['ID','A'], keep=False).values
a = df[~m].index.get_level_values(0).unique()
print(a)
Index(['B001'], dtype='object', name='ID')
```